# How is a slot for each country decided on Pokemon World Championships?

Tags: competitive-gaming, pokemon-seventh-generation

In Pokemon World Championships, there is quite a strong difference on the number of slots allotted to each country. According to [this website](http://assets.pokemon.com/standings/us/worlds/2017/vg/#7_5_0) on the Master category (Day 1 on video game), USA has 36 slots, Japan has 25 slots, and Australia has only 2 slots.

I'm not sure if the chart is correct; some candiates are only shown on the *Top Cut* page, including the champion.

So how is it decided?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple: you need to qualify for it.

The tournaments have a minimum requirement of **Championship Points** (CP). Based on the region you live in you may need a different amount of points (making it "easier" to qualify in less populated regions). How many people from each country are invited depends on how many people meet the minimum requirement.

If you want to earn CP you need to compete in [**Championship Series**](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/pokemon-events/pokemon-tournaments/) events, such as [regional championships](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/pokemon-events/pokemon-tournaments/regional-championships/) or [international championships](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/pokemon-events/pokemon-tournaments/international-championships/) or others. The bigger the event the more points you get.

If you win enough CP to meet the requirements you get invited. Simple, isn't it?

The CP needed to get invited can be found [here](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/pokemon-events/pokemon-tournaments/pokemon-world-championships/).